# How to load assemblies in different directories in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

**Background**

I've got a big, old C# application running on .Net Core 2.2, and I'm trying to add  "hotbin" functionality to it. What I mean is, say my application's entry point is A.dll, and A.dll has a dependency on B.dll (as in, B.dll is referenced by A.dll's .csproj file), and A.dll also loads (via Activator.CreateInstance) classes from C.dll. Therefore, the folder containing the complete, deployed application looks like this:

```
/root/
  |
  +-A.dll
  +-B.dll
  +-C.dll
```

That is, all dlls are on the same level and .NET has no problem locating dependencies for A.dll. The idea behind this "hotbin" functionality is I would like to define a special folder, place dlls in there, bounce the application, and have the application load those dlls instead of the equivalent ones in root. So, going back to the previous example, let's say my folder structure looks like this:

```
/root/
  |
  +-A.dll
  +-B.dll
  +-C.dll
  +-/hotbin/
      |
      +-B.dll
```

When I start up A.dll, I want it to load B.dll from the /hotbin/ folder, not B.dll from the /root/ folder.

**Why I need this**

This app runs in a docker container. If I want to test a bug fix, I'd rather just copy the dll into a folder and bounce the container then create a new docker image with the bug fix and redeploy it.

**What I've tried**

- Adding an "alternateProbingPath" to A.runtimeconfig.json. This seemed to work at first, but after loading all the dlls from A.dll's deps.json, the app crashed when loading dependent dlls from those dlls. Not sure if each dll needs an alternateProbingPath for it's own dependencies, if they do then this is a nonstarter as there are quite a few dlls in this app.
- Moving all dependent dlls to a /local/ folder and writing a "A.Hotbin.dll" which attaches to the AssemblyResolve event before Activator.CreateInstance-ing A.dll and passing control to it.

  In this setup, the app's folder would look like this:

```
/root/
  |
  +-A.hotbin.dll
  +-A.dll
  +-/local/
      |
      +-B.dll
      +-C.dll
```

A.hotbin.dll would intercept all the assembly resolution failures (which would always happen, since none of the dlls are in the same folder as A.dll), check to see if the dll existed in the hotbin folder, and if it didn't load the one in /local/. Again, this almost worked, but after loading the first few dlls the app would crash. No stack trace, no nothing. Just a crash. Attaching a debugger didn't help, as the debugger caused the crash to happen earlier.

- Moving all dependent dlls into a /local/ folder and modifying A.hotbin.dll to load all dlls from that folder into the current AppDomain on startup. This didn't work as AppDomain.Load() takes an assembly name, not a path, and it expects these assemblies to be in the normal place, i.e, next to A.hotbin.dll.

Any other suggestions? Or is there some other way to accomplish this? I've thought about just using docker cp, but the problem is I would need to kill the app to cp in a new dll, and K8S would just restart it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something that seems to work. By combining the last two solutions (have A.hotbin.dll intercept all resolution failures, and have A.hotbin.dll load all dlls in /local/ at startup), it looks like i'm at least able to get the app up and running. I'll test further to make sure it's actually working right and edit this answer if that's the case.

EDIT: Yes, it looks like that works. For future reference, here's what I have:

```
/root/
  |
  +- A.dll
  +- A.hotbin.dll
  +-/local/
      |
      +-B.dll
      +-C.dll
```

I execute A.hotbin.dll instead of A.dll. A.hotbin.dll adds a hook for resolution failures to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`. This hook looks in the /local/ folder for the dll and if it finds it, returns it. If not, returns null (allowing normal dll resolution to continue). A.hotbin.dll then goes into the local folder and iterates over all dlls found in there. For each dll, it tries to load it into the current AppDomain via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllfilename))`. This call will fail to resolve the dll, so it'll call my hook, which will find it. After all dlls have been loaded, A.hotbin.dll Activator.CreateInstance-es A.dll and passes control over.